# C# flow analysis using Roslyn

Tags: c#, semantics, roslyn

I want to

1. traverse a syntax tree to find all `if` / `else` statements,
2. analyze the syntax tree for data flow,
3. gather variables required to calculate the outcome of `if` and `else` blocks,
4. and finally calculate the outcome at each `if` / `else` node.

Is this doable utilizing roslyn?

Comment: in theory yes... in reality there will be several obstacles regarding dependencies (esp. external one like RDBMS, Filesystem etc.).

Comment: and what exactly is your goal ?

Comment: @Yahia, I am imagining to visualize a humongous if block with live data. (red/green dots on conditions).

Comment: @Yahia, I can convert the code to use a specific interface that will be written by me. Nonetheless, interface will need some live collections and lists that will need injection to the roslyn context, I guess.

Comment: @kerem as I said "in theory that is possible"... go ahead and try it and come back with more detailed questions...

Comment: @kerem you might go look at http://github.com/ermau/instant, which I think already does what you want. Incidentally, it was originally built with Roslyn, but as the developer works for Xamarin, it was moved to NRefactory for mono support and a go-live license (since Roslyn is still a CTP).